# What part of my error handling code could be causing Heroku to crash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, error-handling

Problem: I introduced error handling in my code that should render an error page and an error message in the event that something goes wrong. In this specific instance, an error page should show up when a user tried to access a protect route without being signed in. Instead, Heroku just waits 30 seconds and crashes. Oddly, everything works as expected on LocalHost.

While I am not certain, I believe that the error is coming from somewhere in the code below (when the the const sendErrorDev function is called). Everything worked find until I introduced this. However, I am not sure what could be causing the different in outcome in Heroku vs. on LocalHost.

```
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');

const JsonWebTokenError = () =>
  new AppError('Invalid token. Please login again!', 401);

const handleJWTExpiredError = () =>
  new AppError('Your token has EXPIRED! What?!', 401);

const handleCastErrorDB = err => {
  const message = `Invalid ${err.path}: ${err.value}.`;
  return new AppError(message, 400);
};

const handleDuplicateFieldsDB = err => {
  const value = err.errmsg.match(/(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/)[0];
  console.log(value);
  const message = `Duplicate field value: ${value}. Please use another value!`;
  return new AppError(message, 400);
};

const handleValidationErrorDB = err => {
  const errors = Object.values(err.errors).map(el => el.message);
  const message = `Invalid input data. ${errors.join('. ')}`;
  return new AppError(message, 400);
};

const sendErrorDev = (err, req, res) => {
  // A. API
  if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/api')) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode).json({
      status: err.status,
      error: err,
      message: err.message,
      stack: err.stack
    });
  }
  // B. RENDERED WEBSITE
  return res.status(err.statusCode).render('error', {
    title: 'Something went wrong!',
    msg: err.message
  });
};

const sendErrorProd = (err, req, res) => {
  // A) API
  console.log('This is working!!!');
  if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/api')) {
    // A) Trusted operaitonal error, okay to send the details to the client.
    if (err.isOperational) {
      return res.status(err.statusCode).json({
        status: err.status,
        message: err.message
      });
    }
    // Weird coding errors, don't leak the details to the client.
    // 1.) Log the error to the
    console.error('ERROR!', err);
    // 2.) Send generic message to the client
    return res.status(500).json({
      status: 'error',
      message: 'Something went very wrong! JESUS!'
    });
  }
  // B) Rendered Website
  if (err.isOperational) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(err.statusCode).render('error', {
      title: 'Something went wrong!',
      msg: err.message
    });
  }
  // Weird coding errors, don't leak the details to the client.
  // 1.) Log the error to the
  console.error('ERROR!', err);
  // 2.) Send generic message to the client
  return res.status(err.statusCode).render('error', {
    title: 'Something went wrong!',
    msg: 'Please try again later.'
  });
};

module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
  //console.log(err.stack);
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.status = err.status || 'error';

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    sendErrorDev(err, req, res);
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    let error = { ...err };
    error.message = err.message;
    if (error.name === 'CastError') error = handleCastErrorDB(error);
    if (error.code === 11000) error = handleDuplicateFieldsDB(error);
    if (error.name === 'ValidationError')
      error = handleValidationErrorDB(error);
    if (error.name === 'JsonWebTokenError') error = JsonWebTokenError();
    if (error.name === 'TokenExpiredError') error = handleJWTExpiredError();

    sendErrorProd(error, req, res);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In Heroku, I misspelled a config variable. After I corrected, the problem went away.